# Get language strings recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my multilingual program, I fetch the language strings from a language database during language file generation, like this:

```
SELECT [key], translation FROM language WHERE lang=@lang 
UNION 
SELECT [key],translation FROM language WHERE lang='EN'
AND [key] NOT IN(SELECT [key] FROM language WHERE lang=@lang)
```

As you can see, English is the fallback for all languages, should we come across missing translation strings.

The table layout is:

```
[lang] VARCHAR(5)
[key] VARCHAR(100)
[translation] VARCHAR(MAX)
```

Now it would make sense to have a language tree, where every language except "English" has a fallback language defined. Something like this:

```
English
|- English (UK)
|- German
|  |- German (Switzerland)
|  |- German (Austria)
|- French
|  |- French (Canada)
|  |- Italian
|  |- Portuguese
|  |  |- Portuguese (Brazil)
|- Russian
|  |- Czech
```

That way, language strings not (yet) available in Italian may be replaced with language strings from French for the time being, which could be more legible to Italian users than English <sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

Furthermore, German (Switzerland) would only have to contain strings that are really different from German, and would not have to be a complete copy of all strings.

But when fetching the language strings from the database, how would I do that?

I have tried to understand https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx, but I don't get how to add the constraint "only fetch keys that are not yet part of the result set" into the resursive part:

```
WITH MyCTE ([key], translation)
AS
(
    SELECT [key],translation FROM language l1
    WHERE lang = @lang
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [key],translation FROM language l2
    WHERE lang = (SELECT translation FROM language l3 WHERE lang = @lang AND [key] = 'PARENTLANGUAGE')
    AND [key] NOT IN l1
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
```

Sample Table DDT:

```
CREATE TABLE language(
  lang VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  [key] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  [translation] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('EN','YES','Yes');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('EN','NO','No');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('EN','OK','OK');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('EN-US','NO','Nope');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('DE','YES','Ja');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('DE','NO','Nein');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('EN','JANUARY','January');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('DE','JANUARY','Januar');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('DE-AT','JANUARY','Jänner');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('EN-US','PARENTLANGUAGE','EN');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('DE','PARENTLANGUAGE','EN');
INSERT INTO language([lang],[key],[translation]) ('DE-AT','PARENTLANGUAGE','DE');
```

Expected result for `lang = 'DE-AT'`:

```
[key]   translation
-------------------
YES     Ja
NO      Nein
OK      OK
JANUARY Jänner
```

Comment: Please provide sample data http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: How is your child language associated to your parent?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen As of now, there is no connection. I intended to use a translation string (`[key]='PARENTLANGUAGE'`) for this, but I am open for other suggestions.

Comment: @lad2025 I am trying to create a sample, but I am reproducibly getting a `504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT` during insert operation of a single record.

Comment: @lad2025 I have added the sample data into the post, because I can't get SQL fiddle to work. Not sure whether it's the server or a problem with my connection.

Comment: You should make your child languages have a key to your parent, then you can anchor the recursive parts on that.

Comment: SQL is quite bad when it comes to recursion. You usually have to create a dynamic number of queries, which may perform really bad. You probably have to use some caching anyway. Also consider to put everything to memory (starting from root language, following the tree and overriding all that is defined).

Comment: In addition to your language table ( that maps a key to a translation ) you will need a table to record the hierarchy of languages (that maps a language to its 'parent' or fallback language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible option. I'll go ahead and say that this is almost certainly not the most elegant way to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Languages
(
    lang varchar(5) not null CONSTRAINT PK_Languages PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    langparen varchar(5) null CONSTRAINT FK_Languages_Parent FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Languages(lang)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Translations
(
    translation_id int not null identity(1,1),
    [key] varchar(100) not null,
    lang varchar(5) not null constraint FK_Translations_Languages FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Languages(lang),
    translation varchar(MAX) not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Translations PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED([key],lang)
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_Translations ON dbo.Translations (translation_id);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Languages
(lang, langparen)
SELECT 'EN', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EN-US', 'EN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DE', 'EN'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DE-AT', 'DE';

INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('EN','YES','Yes');
INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('EN','NO','No');
INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('EN','OK','OK');
INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('EN-US','NO','Nope');
INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('DE','YES','Ja');
INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('DE','NO','Nein');
INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('EN','JANUARY','January');
INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('DE','JANUARY','Januar');
INSERT INTO dbo.Translations([lang],[key],[translation]) VALUES('DE-AT','JANUARY','Jänner');

go


with recurse as
(
    select lang, langparen, lvl = 0, list = cast(lang as varchar(8000)) from dbo.Languages where langparen IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    select lang.lang, lang.langparen, paren.lvl + 1, list = cast(paren.list + ',' + lang.lang as varchar(8000))
    FROM dbo.Languages lang
    JOIN recurse paren ON paren.lang = lang.langparen 
)
select * into #recurse from recurse

declare @lang varchar(100) = 'DE-AT';

declare @langstring varchar(8000);

select @langstring = list from #recurse where lang = @lang

;WITH lists AS
(
SELECT t.*, rid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[key] order by lvl desc)
FROM dbo.Translations t
join #recurse r ON t.lang = r.lang
join dbo.split (@langstring, ',') s on s.Item = t.lang
)

SELECT * FROM lists where rid = 1
```

Some of the key points:

1. I made a separate Languages table that had both a given language and its most immediate parent, so that I could build a hierarchy for the tree, as you mention above. I called the translations table "Translations".
2. I wrote a recursive query that also combined the "path" of the tree, from the top down. This could almost certainly be done more elegantly using the `hierarchy` datatype, but I find this way less fiddly.
3. For the main query, I pull both the recursive results as well as the string from the highest level ("De-At" in this case). The recursive results let you do a `ROW_NUMBER` call that starts at the highest "level" of your recursion and work your way down, for each available key.